# Force garbage collection manually

Tags: java

Is there a good way to force garbage collection manually in Java?

Are methods like `System.gc()` and `Runtime.gc()` guaranteeing that garbage collection will happen at the time it calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to manually force Java GC with 100% probability.

Moreover you can have a GC which does no actual work e.g. [JEP 318 Epsilon, A No-Op Garbage Collector](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/318).